# Is it possible to add a new rule to a running Drools session?

Tags: java, drools

Hey there, I've got a project at work that may require me to load/unload rules to a stateful Drools session during the run of the program. (Eventually using JMX, but for now I'm just trying to add a rule to a ready-made session)

I was wondering, is this possible and in that case how? Do I need to rebuild the session? I have attempted to simply get the knowledge base from the session, add my rule file to it and then fire all rules, which didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is YES, here's a quote from the [documentation](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.1.1.34858.FINAL/drools-expert/html/ch03.html#d0e1414):

> 3.2.5. StatefulknowledgeSessions and KnowledgeBase Modifications
>
> Stateful Knowledge Sessions will be discussed in more detail in section "Running". The KnowledgeBase creates and returns StatefulKnowledgeSession objects, and it may optionally keep references to those. When KnowledgeBase modifications occur those modifications are applied against the data in the sessions. This reference is a weak reference and it is also optional, which is controlled by a boolean flag.

Comment: So for all intents and purposes, if the rules are properly loaded into the KnowledgeBase, all sessions related to that KB are also updated? That would mean my current problem is loading, not updating. I'll put my nose to the grindstone again, thanks!

Comment: Yes - it will update everything, including taking into account any existing facts (you will of course need to call "fireAllRules" or similar after adding/removing rules. This is a core feature of many rule engines and something that can work well, although it is far from common in practice.